# What is a word that means "not ashamed"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, the sentence *I am not ashamed of my past*. *Indifferent to* sounds too passive, *proud of* sounds too strong. Any ideas?

Comment: A sample sentence please!!

Comment: @Ibf _For example, the sentence "I am not ashamed of my past"_

Comment: unapologetic, remorseless, unrepentant, not sorry for?

Comment: In what sense are you intending to use this word?  Are you **proud** because you've diligently striven to lead a good life,  **confident** because you know of no shameful events, or **defiant** because you vehemently disagree with others who think you should be ashamed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are "not ashamed" of your past, would you be [unashamed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unashamed)?  This word minimizes other possible connotations of your sentence.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unashamed): Definition of unashamed : not ashamed : being without
>   guilt, self-consciousness, or doubt
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unashamed?s=t): not ashamed; not restrained by embarrassment or consciousness of moral guilt